# Achievements not registering in Steam

Tags: achievements, dungeon-defenders

I'm playing Dungeons Defenders solo and my achievements pop in game, but when I go to my Steam profile, everything is still locked.

Do I have to play multiplayer for Steam achievements or did I hit a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To unlock achievements on steam you need to play online on Trendynet, as long as it is on Trendynet it does not matter if you are alone or with other people. There is also a small deley from unlocking them in game till they show up on steam.